# I can't back press between fragments when clicking back press button

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, android-architecture-navigation

I am implementing an android application in kotlin and i can't navigate back between fragments and i get warning like :

> Cancelling event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_BACK, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x68, repeatCount=0, eventTime=224793910, downTime=224793513, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=0 }

. How could i figure it out ? Here is my xml file content :

> 

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/splash_fragment">
    
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/splash_fragment"
            android:name="com.xxx.yyy.splash.fragment.SplashFragment"
            android:label="SplashFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
            <action android:id="@+id/action_splash_to_account_management"
                app:destination="@id/account_management_fragment"/>
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_splash_fragment_to_identity_fragment_with_camera"
                app:destination="@id/identity_fragment_with_camera" />
        </fragment>
 
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/privacy_policy_fragment"
            android:name="com.xxx.yyy.presentation.privacy_policy.fragment.PrivacyPolicyFragment"
            android:label="PrivacyPolicyFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_privacy_policy">
    
            <action android:id="@+id/action_privacy_policy_to_verif_number"
                app:destination="@id/verif_number_fragment"/>
        </fragment>
    
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/verif_number_fragment"
            android:name="com.xxx.yyy.presentation.register.fragment.VerifNumberFragment"
            android:label="VerifNumberFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_verif_number">
            <action android:id="@+id/action_verif_number_to_verif_otp"
                app:destination="@id/verif_otp_fragment"/>
    
        </fragment>
   
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/identity_fragment_with_camera"
            android:name="com.xxx.yyy.Cameraphoto"
            android:label="fragment_identity_with_camera"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_identity_with_camera" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_identity_fragment_with_camera_to_selfieCamera"
                app:destination="@id/selfieCamera" />
            <argument
                android:name="imageUri"
                app:argType="string"
                android:defaultValue="@null"
                app:nullable="true"/>
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_identity_fragment_with_camera_to_videoRecorder"
                app:destination="@id/videoRecorder" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/selfieCamera"
            android:name="com.xxx.yyy.SelfieCamera"
            android:label="fragment_selfie_camera"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_selfie_camera" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_selfieCamera_to_identity_fragment_with_camera"
                app:destination="@id/identity_fragment_with_camera" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/videoRecorder"
            android:name="com.xxx.yyy.VideoRecorder"
            android:label="fragment_video_recorder"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_video_recorder" >
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_videoRecorder_to_identity_fragment_with_camera"
                app:destination="@id/identity_fragment_with_camera" />
        </fragment>
    
    
    </navigation>
```

And this is how i navigate through fragment :

```
            mainNavController().navigate(SplashFragmentDirections.actionSplashFragmentToIdentityFragmentWithCamera(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the piece of code that handles back press?
The issue doesn't seem to relate to navigation.

1. Make sure you're using the right method like "findNavController().navigateUp()"
2. Check the onBackPressed() method handled properly
3. Ensure that your navigation is set up correctly NavGraph, NavHostFrament and so on.
4. Search for any custom interceptors or listeners that interfere with back press

Comment: ,through my researches , i saw that when it comes to fragment , we don't have to handle navigation back between them ... that's why i did not understand why the back press button doesn't work